# Notification working on background PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a web application that use notification to inform user about anything new (just like Facebook).

My solution is that I send a request every three seconds to check the database if there is anything new to display (jQuery and AJAX). However, this makes the application slow, since a request is sent to check tables every three seconds.

I want to know how to make these notifications work without interrupting the application.

Comment: Maybe 3 seconds is just too short? Otherwise you can use asynchronous communication

Comment: When doing polling, don't use a fixed time interval. Instead set a new timeout when the previous request has completely finished.

Comment: @AamirAfridi how does nodejs help you write in browser javascript?

Comment: Why not have a single table that becomes updated based on anything new, and check that every few seconds. Then if there is any changes in that table, it will fetch the changes from the associated table. It will reduce checks and data send/receive. A simple boolean check.

Comment: @Slimen, what do you mean "makes the application slow"? Do you mean it take too long for changes to show up? What is this for, do you really need up to the second changes? Facebook only polls once per 30 seconds for notifications, can you really not wait for 30 seconds to see if someone liked your photo?

Do you mean your actual code blocks for a long time because it waits for the ajax response before it can do anything else? In that case you might want to consider looking at jquery deferred objects http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html

Comment: @HansZ, yes my code blocks while waiting the ajax response.And about facebook u can notice that when you like my photo (for example) I get the notification in 1 sec not in 30 sec like u said !

Comment: @StuartWickenden,yes I'm using only one table actually but still my code blocks for a while until I get the ajax response.

Comment: Can you show some code, AJAX PHP requests normally takes milliseconds. Perhaps there is an issue in a method you are using?

Comment: @StuartWickenden, I'm not using my PC now but here is the global idea:

Comment: I have a hidden input that contain the id of the last checked news then I use setTimeout function and send every 3 secondes this last id using SELECT request and check if there is a new id added to the table ,if yes I get the news and put the new id in the hidden input and do the verification again.

Comment: This definitely sounds like we'd need to see your code. Please ask this question again with an example of what you're doing and we'd be able to help you better.

Comment: ok thnx for your patience :)

Comment: @StuartWickenden :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982798/notification-on-background-php

Comment: @HansZ:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982798/notification-on-background-php

Comment: and thnx again for ur help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

**[WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)**

You can connect to server from modern browser and get notifications **instantly**.

For PHP context you can use [Ratchet](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet).

**Bonus**

PHP setup from bigger application (what I am currently using):

- Normal Symfony as backend app (handles regular/ajax requests)
- Symfony command as websocket server ([Ratchet](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet))
- Redis as message storage
- Symfony command for task scheduling (rewritten [php-resque](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque) to suit my needs)
- Symfony command for task execution
- AngularJS + Autobahn.js for frontend

**NOTE:**
Question had `PHP` tag on it which was removed by 3rd party edit.

Comment: according to caniuse, only 72.24% of web traffic uses browsers that support websockets. http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: Websockets scales better than AJAX every second or so with number of users, plus you have real *real time updates*.

Comment: If your ajax don't scale neither does your website.