# Notification on background PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a web application that use notification to inform user about anything new (just like Facebook).

My solution is that I send a request every three seconds to check the database if there is anything new to display (jQuery and AJAX). However, this makes the application slow, since a request is sent to check tables every three seconds.

I want to know how to make these notifications work without interrupting the application.

So this is my JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    

    LoopNotificationCRM();

  });
    function LoopNotificationCRM(){
  setTimeout('LoopNotificationCRM();',3000);
  $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "controllers/c_ajax_notification.php",
            data: "ordre=check_new_notification",
            success: function(msg){
              if(msg != 'NAN'){
               var t = msg.split('***');
               $('.sNotification').html(t[0]);
               $('.ul-notification').html(t[1]);
               $('.alert-notification').css('display','block');
              }else{
               $('.sNotification').html(0);
               $('.alert-notification').css('display','none');
               $('.ul-notification').html('');
              }
            }, 
          error: function (xhr, status) {  
            alert('Erreur: ' + status); 
            } 
         });
}
```

And this is my PHP Code:

```
$notification->getNewNotification("*");
         if($notification->db_num_row != 0){
                      $listNoti = '';
                      while($resN = $notification->fetch_array()){
                       $today = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                       $datNoti = new DateTime($resN['date_not_crm']);

                       $diff = $datNoti->diff($today);
                       if($diff->d == 0){
                         if($diff->h == 0){
                           if($diff->i == 0){
                              $intervale = 'il y a '.$diff->s.' sec';
                           }else{
                              $intervale = 'il y a '.$diff->i.' min';
                           }                           
                         }else{
                           $intervale = 'il y a '.$diff->h.' heure(s)';
                         }
                       }else{
                           $intervale = 'il y a '.$diff->d.' jour(s)';
                       }

       $listNoti .= '<li>  
                                 <a onclick="link(event,\''.$resN['url_not_crm'].'\');updateEtatNoti(this,'.$resN['id_not_crm'].');" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                 <span class="label label-icon label-success"><i class="'.$resN['icon_not_crm'].'"></i></span>
                                 '.$notification->csNotification($resN['description_not_crm']).' 
                                 <span class="time">'.$intervale.'</span>
                                 </a>
                              </li>';
                     }

            echo $notification->getCountNewNotification().'***'.$listNoti;
        }else{
         echo 'NAN';
        }
```

When I remove the notification code my application become more fast !

Comment: Try it with `async: true,`

Comment: "this makes application slow" - how slow? It takes a long time to obtain the response from server? Your browser is blocked while you wait for the response (it is since async is false)? Your query is too heavy for MySQL and your server? Please be more elaborate.

Comment: I second Andy Gee, use async: true as this will start the process in another thread.

Comment: @AndyGee, thnx for ur answer this is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is slowing down when you run the ajax every 3 seconds, try simplifying/shrinking the amount of work the page loaded by the ajax needs to do.  Rather than reading an entire table, for example, try selecting only notifications with a "read" status of 0.  That way, the .php file is faster to execute, meaning the ajax will not slow down the page as much.

Comment: in this function $notification->getNewNotification("*"); I only select notifications with status = 0;

Comment: By the way the application is slow only on internet but in local works perfect even with this code !

Comment: Basically, it all comes down to speed of the .php file.  If that's fast, the ajax will be fast.  If that's slow, the ajax will be slow.  If you use async, then that will not be the case, because the ajax will be offloaded into another thread.

Comment: so what do you suggest ?

Comment: use "async: true" will help, but because I don't know all of the PHP behind `getNewNotification` and such, I can't say for certain what would be slowing it down.

Comment: this is the function:public function getNewNotification($values){
   gest_sql::select($values,"notification_crm","etat_not_crm = 0","id_not_crm DESC");
  }

Comment: Have you tried using "async:true"?  That's going to make the largest difference, since you browser will have 2 threads - 1 for the page content, 1 for loading new content form the AJAX.  If you need to run speed trials on your PHP code and find what things are slow, check out [XDebug profiling](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler).

Comment: actually it did a diffrence, thnx guys :)

Comment: If the answer helped, please accept it as the accepted answer or upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the use of `async:true` may not play nice with older computers, as it requires a separate thread for processing.